# SQL - Count total IDs each day between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what my data looks like

```
ID       StartDate        EndDate
1        1/1/2019         1/15/2019
2        1/10/2019        1/11/2019
3        2/5/2020         3/10/2020
4        3/10/2019        3/19/2019
5        5/1/2020         5/4/2020
```

I am trying to get a list of every date in my data set,and how many IDs fall in that time range, aggregated to the date level. So for ID-1, it would be in the records for 1/1/2019, 1/2/2019...through 1/15/2019.

I am not sure how to do this. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a calendar table (highly recommended), you can perform this task with an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[StartDate] date,[EndDate] date)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'1/1/2019','1/15/2019')
,(2,'1/10/2019','1/11/2019')
,(3,'2/5/2020','3/10/2020')
,(4,'3/10/2019','3/19/2019')
,(5,'5/1/2020','5/4/2020')


Select A.ID
      ,B.Date
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,A.[StartDate],A.[EndDate])+1) Date=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),A.[StartDate])  
                From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
                ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Date
1   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
1   2019-01-03
1   2019-01-04
1   2019-01-05
1   2019-01-06
1   2019-01-07
1   2019-01-08
1   2019-01-09
1   2019-01-15
2   2019-01-10
2   2019-01-11
....
5   2020-05-01
5   2020-05-02
5   2020-05-03
5   2020-05-04
```